# Securimage works locally but not on server

Tags: php, captcha

Securimage is working as expected when tested locally, but when uploaded to the server it is not displaying the image and does not seem to be resetting the text. Look here for an example:  http://www.localtel.net/zz_Contact.php

Any suggestions on what may need to be set differently or changed on the server.  All files have been uploaded and the mappings seem to be fine.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When [accessing the captcha image directly](http://www.localtel.net/securimage/securimage_show.php?be309d58b4016896cd2f122aefffe623) it shows this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreate() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\securimage\securimage.php on line 1418
```

It appears your server hasn't got the [GD module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) installed, which is used to generate images on the fly.